# Is there a file like the designer.cs from WinForms in WPF?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I should recreate MineSweeper in either WinForms or WPF (homework). I wanted to learn something new, so I started my project as wpf. I want to welcome the player as he starts my program, so I added another window (wpf) called "intro". First I added a TextBox, but now I'm using a Label. I deleted the textbox, but I still have the error "CS1061" and I don't know how to fix it. I thought maybe I need to delete the old textbox like I would delete an item in Winforms, I'd go into designer.cs, mark the code and delete it. Is there such a file like the designer from WinForms in WPF? -> my guess is that the "old textbox" is still active somewhere. If that's not the problem, can somebody tell me how I can fix this error? Sorry if I made any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: I think you have some more info as well as the error number and it would probably have been easier to help if you mentioned all the rest of the error description. You can get cs1061 if you don't have a handler in your code file matching one allocated in xaml.

Comment: If you want to learn something new I would look at MVVM and WPF, for this the code behind (design.cs) is not needed, and it is common stile to use MVVM with wpf.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF the xaml files have a code behind file. If you expand the MainWindow.xaml in the solution explorer there will be a MainWindow.xaml.cs file.

There may be something in the code behind that is causing your error. Not going to be able to help more without a more detailed error message or a code sample.

Comment: I just made a little mistake, got it now. Thanks for your comment!